# Getting error when reloading page in jquery success call in mvc4 jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have view called detailsbyClientId.cshtml which displays table data(data binded through model) and some buttons. When i click on button i am calling actionmethod and i will do some calculations in controller(i will process some rows of data).
Below is jquery code.
My button
       
Jquery Code.

```
function batchSave()
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var clientId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.detailsbyclientId[0].clientId));
        var ids = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Ids));
        var arr = jQuery.makeArray(ids);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'clientId':clientId,'uploadidList': arr.join()},
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/documentVerification/batchSave',
            success: function (data) {
            fun_toastr_notify('success', 'Document have been Approved');
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");

                $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
                                     }
                   , error: function (error) {
                       fun_toastr_notify('error', data, 'Error');
                   }
        });
        });

    }
```

This is my controller code.

```
public JsonResult batchSave(int? clientId, int? currentFilter, int? page,string uploadidList)
        {
          documentVerificationBAL objBAL = new documentVerificationBAL();
          int[] myuploadId = uploadidList.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
          foreach(var indId in myuploadId)
            {
               int latupdateVersion= objBAL.getlatestVersion(indId);
               if(latupdateVersion>1)
                {
                   List<uploadanddocContent> uploadanddocContent = objBAL.metadataexternalUsers(indId, latupdateVersion);
                   foreach(var data in uploadanddocContent)
                    {
                       int Status = UploadDocument.SaveUploadContent(data.upld_Value, data.upld_Label, indId, data.doc_contentId);
                       if(Status==1)
                        {
                            int latStatus = objBAL.updateMasterTable(indId);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            if (clientId != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                clientId = currentFilter;
            }
            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = clientId;
            int pageSize = 8;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            int cId = Convert.ToInt32(clientId);
            List<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclient = objBAL.detailsbyclient(cId);
            IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> pagedLog = detailsbyclient.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

            detailsbyclientIdviewModel model;
            model = new detailsbyclientIdviewModel()
            {
                detailsbyclientId = pagedLog,
                Ids = pagedLog.Select(x => x.upld_Id)
            };
            return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //return View("detailsbyClientId", model);
        }
```

Inside batchSave action method i will do some calculation so that next time some rows should not display after clicking on button. My view is not getting updated because i am not handling anything in success call. So can someone suggest me how can i achieve this? thank you. I tried with location.reload but in the below line i am getting error var clientId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.detailsbyclientId[0].clientId));
View page

```
@if (Model.detailsbyclientId != null)
{
    <div>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataTable tableHover">
            <tr>
                <th>Corporate Name</th>
                <th>employee ID</th>
                <th>employee Name</th>
                <th>Nationality</th>
                <th>Document Type</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var group in Model.detailsbyclientId)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td> @group.clientName </td>
                    <td> @group.employeeId </td>
                    <td> @group.employeeName </td>
                    <td>@group.Nationality</td>
                    <td> @group.documentType </td>
                    <td scope="col">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" value="View Document" onclick="showDocumentData('@group.upld_Id');" />
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td scope="col">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" value="Done" onclick="batchSave();" />
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" value="Cancel" onclick="batchCancel();" />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model.detailsbyclientId, page => Url.Action("detailsbyClientId",
    new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, pageSize = 5 }))
        Page @(Model.detailsbyclientId.PageCount < Model.detailsbyclientId.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.detailsbyclientId.PageNumber) of @Model.detailsbyclientId.PageCount
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div>No records found</div>
}
```

Comment: There is no point using ajax if you were to use `location.reload` which refreshes the whole page (you might as well do a normal submit). What do you mean by _so that next time some rows should not display after clicking on button_? Do you just want to update the current page so that some of its html is removed? And why are you using `arr.join()` to convert the array to a string and then converting it back again on the server - just use `data: { clientId: clientId, uploadidList: ids },` and change the method parameter to `int[] uploadidList`

Comment: yes i want to update current page so that some of its html is removed. Yes i will make changes as you said(arrays)

Comment: Then you can just use `$(someElement').remove();` in the success callback, although its not clear what you want to remove, and based on what conditions

Comment: The alternative (not as efficient) is to return a new partial view of that part of the DOM you want updated and replace it.

Comment: I will change the status of some rows of data so that when i click on button those rows will update in db and those rows should get rid off from current page

Comment: Still not clear (and you should edit your question so it is), but best guess is that your method needs to return a JsonResult` containing a property which is an array of the items you want deleted (perhaps their ID's, or their index in the collection, so you can loop through that array on the client and remove the associated DOM elements

Comment: Yes i can get that rows in json result through thier indexes but how can i remove associated DOM elements? I will show my view page above.

Comment: Something like `success: function (data) { $.each(data, function(index, rowNum) { $('table').children('tr').eq(rowNum).remove(); }); });` where in the method you use `var data = new int[]{ .... }; return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` (if the value of data was say `[0, 3, 4]`, then the 1st, 4th and 5th rows would be removed)

Comment: Okay thanks i will try. Can you put answer please

Comment: No, because I am still not sure exactly what your needing to do, and some of the code have shown does not make any sense

Comment: var clientId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.detailsbyclientId[0].clientId));
        alert(clientId);
        var ids = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Ids));
        var arr = jQuery.makeArray(ids);
        var uploadidList=arr.join();
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = '@Url.Action("batchSave", "documentVerification")?clientId='+clientId+'&uploadidList='+uploadidList+'';
            window.location.href = url;
        } it is working like charm now

Comment: Why in the world would you use `window.location.href = url;` in an ajax call. The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page, but all you doing is a redirect to refresh the whole page again - its just pointless. If you want to refresh the page, then make a normal submit (not ajax) and redirect in the POST method - you will same yourself a whole lot of pointless code and get better performance.

Comment: I am sorry. I am confused how to handle this